# Selected option doesn't update if it references nested property

Tags: c#, html, ajax, asp.net-core, partial-views

I am using .NET Core 3.1 to develop an internal web portal. There is a simple form where whole form must be refreshed with new data if `ProjectId` is changed. Currently, there is only one field (`AssigneeId`) for demonstration purposes, but in reality, there are 15+ inputs that should have their default value set based on selected `ProjectId`.

[image]

For populating the form with new data once `ProjectId` changes, I use AJAX and .NET Core's partial views.

`HomeController.cs`:

```cs
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly List<AppUser> _users = new List<AppUser>()
    {
        new AppUser() { Id = 1, DisplayName = "Kobe Bryant" },
        new AppUser() { Id = 2, DisplayName = "Michael Jordan" },
        new AppUser() { Id = 3, DisplayName = "Steve Nash" },
        new AppUser() { Id = 4, DisplayName = "Kevin Durant" },
        new AppUser() { Id = 5, DisplayName = "James Harden" }
    };

    private readonly List<Project> _projects = new List<Project>()
    {
        new Project() { Id = 1, Name = "Asset API" },
        new Project() { Id = 2, Name = "Reservation API" },
        new Project() { Id = 3, Name = "Payment API" }
    };

    private readonly Dictionary<int, int> _projectMaintainers = new Dictionary<int, int>()
    {
        { 1, 2 },
        { 2, 4 },
        { 3, 5 },
    };
    
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.AllProjects = new SelectList(_projects, nameof(Project.Id), nameof(Project.Name));
        ViewBag.AllAssignees = new SelectList(_users, nameof(AppUser.Id), nameof(AppUser.DisplayName));
        
        return View(GetDefaultGuiModelData(3));
    }

    public IActionResult GetFormPartial(int projectId)
    {
        ViewBag.AllProjects = new SelectList(_projects, nameof(Project.Id), nameof(Project.Name));
        ViewBag.AllAssignees = new SelectList(_users, nameof(AppUser.Id), nameof(AppUser.DisplayName));
        return PartialView("_Form", GetDefaultGuiModelData(projectId));
    }

    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    private CreateInvoiceGuiModel GetDefaultGuiModelData(int projectId)
    {
        return new CreateInvoiceGuiModel()
        {
            NestedData = new NestedData()
            {
                ProjectId = projectId,
                AssigneeId = _projectMaintainers[projectId]
            }
        };
    }
}

public class AppUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}

public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

`CreateInvoiceGuiModel.cs`:

```cs
public class CreateInvoiceGuiModel
{
    public NestedData NestedData { get; set; }
}

public class NestedData
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public int? AssigneeId { get; set; }
}
```

`Index.cshtml`:

```cs
@model SelectListTest.Web.Models.CreateInvoiceGuiModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Create" id="createInvoiceForm">
            @await Html.PartialAsync("_Form")
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts
{
    <script src="~/js/Index.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
}
```

`_Form.cshtml`:

```cs
@model SelectListTest.Web.Models.CreateInvoiceGuiModel

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="NestedData.ProjectId" class="control-label"></label>
            <select asp-for="NestedData.ProjectId" class="form-control" id="projectIdSelect" asp-items="ViewBag.AllProjects" required></select>
            <span asp-validation-for="NestedData.ProjectId" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="NestedData.AssigneeId" class="control-label"></label>
            <select asp-for="NestedData.AssigneeId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.AllAssignees" required></select>
            <span asp-validation-for="NestedData.AssigneeId" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`Index.js`:

```js
$(document).ready(onDocumentReady);

function onDocumentReady() {
    $('#projectIdSelect').on('change', function () {
        var selectedProjectId = this.value;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: `/Home/GetFormPartial?projectId=${selectedProjectId}`,
            success: function (html) {
                console.log(html);
                $('#createInvoiceForm').html(html);
                onDocumentReady();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

When I change the `ProjectId`, the following HTML is returned from the server. As you can see, *Kevin Durant* is selected option, **but the GUI doesn't reflect that**!

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="NestedData_ProjectId">ProjectId</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="projectIdSelect" required data-val="true" data-val-required="The ProjectId field is required." name="NestedData.ProjectId">
                <option value="1">Asset API</option>
                <option selected="selected" value="2">Reservation API</option>
                <option value="3">Payment API</option>
            </select>
            <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="NestedData.ProjectId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="NestedData_AssigneeId">AssigneeId</label>
            <select class="form-control" required id="NestedData_AssigneeId" name="NestedData.AssigneeId">
                <option value="1">Kobe Bryant</option>
                <option value="2">Michael Jordan</option>
                <option value="3">Steve Nash</option>
                <option selected="selected" value="4">Kevin Durant</option>
                <option value="5">James Harden</option>
            </select>
            <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="NestedData.AssigneeId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

**INTERESTINGLY**, it looks like .NET Core has problems with `<select>`s and nested properties? If I change `CreateInvoiceGuiModel` to (I removed nested properties, deleted `NestedData` class) ...:

```cs
public class CreateInvoiceGuiModel
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public int? AssigneeId { get; set; }
}
```

... and update the partial view to (`ProjectId` and `AssigneeId` are not inside nested class anymore) ...:

```cs
@model SelectListTest.Web.Models.CreateInvoiceGuiModel

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="ProjectId" class="control-label"></label>
            <select asp-for="ProjectId" class="form-control" id="projectIdSelect" asp-items="ViewBag.AllProjects" required></select>
            <span asp-validation-for="ProjectId" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="AssigneeId" class="control-label"></label>
            <select asp-for="AssigneeId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.AllAssignees" required></select>
            <span asp-validation-for="AssigneeId" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

... it seems to work. `AssigneeId` is correctly updated once `ProjectId` changes. Why is that the case? Does .NET Core have problems with nested properties inside `<select asp-for="">` helper?

Comment: What doesn't change? Is it reaching the controller method? If you out a breakpoint in the `success` does it hit it? Also, instead of doing this `$(document).ready(onDocumentReady);` and then calling the function again later, why don't you just wrap the code in a `.on('ready', function(){`?